# Exchange integral and summation for particular function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
$I_n=(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}), \chi_{I_n}$ is an indicator function on $I_n$.
For a sequence of real numbers $\phi_n$ with $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty|\phi_n|<\infty$, it is easy to see that $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \phi_nn\chi_{I_n} $ is integrable. However, can I change the integral and summation for this function?
i.e., $\int_0^1\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\phi_nn\chi_{I_n}=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\phi_nn\chi_{I_n}$? I tried to use D.C.T. but I can't find proper function to bound this. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

First, observe that
$$ \Big|\sum_{n=1}^{N}n\phi_n\chi_{I_n}\Big|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|\phi_n|\chi_{I_n}$$
for each $N$, and by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$$ \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|\phi_n|\chi_{I_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1n|\phi_n|\chi_{I_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\phi_n|}{n+1}<\infty$$

Therefore the function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|\phi_n|\chi_{I_n}$ is integrable, so is finite almost everywhere (note that this is also clear from the fact that the $I_n$ are disjoint).

Hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\phi_n\chi_{I_n}$ converges almost everywhere, and it follows from the Dominated Convergence Theorem (with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|\phi_n|\chi_{I_n}$ as the dominating function) that
$$ \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\phi_n\chi_{I_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1n\phi_n\chi_{I_n}$$

Comment: Oh I did the first part of the proof but did not think of that. Thanks!